# CodeIgniter routing with two segment is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

I am working with CodeIgniter with multiple languages and city website. For multiple languages below route is working fine ( URL = `www.mywebsite.com/en/`)

```
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Multilingual routing (use 2 characters (e.g. en, zh, cn, es) for switching languages)
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
$route['^(\w{2})/(.*)$'] = '$2';
$route['^(\w{2})$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

But when the URL like `www.mywebsite.com/en/del/` then the route is not working, code like below

```
$route['^(\w{2})/^(\w{3})$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

where i am wrong, any idea?

Comment: Are these variables being passed to a method in the controller? Also, it seems that you have routing backwards. You are supposed to assign the `$route[$variable]` a value, not the other way around. In your case, it's supposed to be like this: 

`$route['default_controller'] = $route['^(\w{2})/^(\w{3})$'];` .... Unless you are trying to say that the default controller should be activated when that regex is found.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your regex is incorrect, `^` marks the beginning of the string and you can't using it in the mid like this. Try using the following code instead([DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eNYPmJ/1)):

```
$route['^(\w{2})/(\w{3})$'] = $route['default_controller'];
```

Comment: it's working fine once i remove the code $route['^(\w{2})/(.*)$'] = '$2'; otherwise it's not working.

Comment: OK, then remove `$route['^(\w{2})/(.*)$'] = '$2';`